# MongoDB/Mongoose aggregate with lookup, nested arrays, sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So, these are my models

```
let restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: 'string',
    restId: 'string',
    saved: {type: 'date', default: Date.now()}
})

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {type: 'string', default: ''},
    lastName: {type: 'string', default: ''},
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    beenTo: [restaurantSchema],
    toGoTo: [restaurantSchema]
})
```

I want to make a feed: 'user A wants to go to restaurant X, user B wants to go to restaurant Y, user A has been to restaurant Z', etc, all sorted primarily by the date. so I've been trying to use aggregate to come up with documents that contain the username and restaurant name, as well as the timestamp, such that I could sort all the documents, regardless of username, with a {'saved': -1}, or whatever the timestamp becomes.

Here's about what I've got so far

```
User.aggregate([
    {$match: {username: {$ne: username}}},
    {$lookup: {
      from: "restaurants",
      localField: "beenTo.saved",
      foreignField: "saved",
      as: "savRest"
    }},
    {$project: {'savRest.saved': 1, 'savRest.name': 1, 'username': 1}},
    {$group: {
      _id: null,
      sav: {$push: '$savRest.saved'}
    }}
  ])
```

Given the arrays, I expect i need to $unwind at some point, but I'm not sure where in the pipeline that goes...

Comment: From your schema it looks like Restaurant is a sub document of user doc, `beenTo : [RestaurantSchema]`. This will store the restaurant doc as a sub-doc of user object,In this case, $lookup wont work as you want it to. if you want to store just the restaurant id in the array, and refere from actual restaurant document, you need to change your schema : `beenTo : [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.Object, ref : 'Restaurant']`. If i misunderstood your question, please edit it to make it more understandable. It is little bit confusing here.

Comment: I see. Sorry if it's confusing, I'm trying to understand most of this myself. In this case, supposing I made the suggested edit to my schema, can I then get to the desired result?

Comment: Yes you can, please tell me the exact thing you want, and i will help you out. what are you trying to achieve with the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: I ultimately want to sort all the entries in all (other) users beenTo and toGoTo arrays by date, starting from the most recent.

Comment: So you want all the users, except the given user , that is why you have written : `username : {$ne : username}` right?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restructure your `schema`, and include only the restaurant `_id` in the user document, instead of storing whole restaurant `doc` as a `sub-document`.

Please change your `userSchema` into this:

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {type: 'string', default: ''},
    lastName: {type: 'string', default: ''},
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    beenTo: [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : "Restaurant"}],
    toGoTo: [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : "Restaurant"}]
})
```

See the change i have done to your schema, instead of storing the restaurant document, we will only be storing its _id(ObjectId).

And to fetch all the restaurants and sort them, you can do the following:

```
User.aggregate([
    {$match: {username: {$ne: username}}},
    // need to unwind the array, before we can do a $lookup over it
    {$unwind : "beenTo"},
    {$lookup: {
      from: "restaurants",
      localField: "beenTo",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "beenTo"
    }},

    //need to unwind again, as $lookup returns an array
    {$unwind : "beenTo"},

    //sort the result by beenTo.saved (date) first.
    {$sort : {"$beenTo.saved" : -1}},

    //after sorting, group all the docs and created sorted beenTo array
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$_id",
            firstName : {$first : "$firstName"},
            lastName : {$first : "$lastName"},
            username : {$first : "$username"},
            beenTo : {$push : "$beenTo"},
            toGoTo : {$first : "$toGoTo"}
        }
    },

    //after sorting of beenTo, we can go for sorting of toGoTo array, 
    // we will follow the same procedure again.
    {$unwind : "toGoTo"},
    {$lookup: {
      from: "restaurants",
      localField: "toGoTo",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "toGoTo"
    }},

    //need to unwind again, as $lookup returns an array
    {$unwind : "toGoTo"},

    {$sort : {"$toGoTo.saved" : -1}},
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$_id",
            firstName : {$first : "$firstName"},
            lastName : {$first : "$lastName"},
            username : {$first : "$username"},
            beenTo : {$first : "$beenTo"}
            toGoTo : {$push : "$toGoTo"},
        }
    }
  ])
```

**Explanation of aggregation pipeline:**

1. `$match` : Required to match all the selected documents.
2. `$unwind` : We need to unwind the array (`beenTo`),before we can do a lookup on it.
3. `$lookup` : populated the respected restaurant document from restaurant collection
4. `$unwind` : `$lookup` returns an array, we need to convert it to object again.
5. `$sort` : sort all the docs according to `beenTo.saved` value
6. `$group` : Group all the docs based on _id of users, and push all the `beenTo` docs to its array. (Now we have the `beenTo` array populated with restaurant docs, and sorted too)
7. `$unwind` : Next we need to unwind `toGoTo` array, so that we can perform its lookup
8. `$lookup` : To populate respective docs from restaurant collection
9. `$unwind` : Again we need to unwind, as `$lookup` returns an array
10. `$sort` : Sort all the docs according to toGoTo.saved field
11. `$group` : Group all the docs based on users `_id`, and push all the `toGoTo` docs to its array, and `beenTo` will remain the same.

Hence, at the end of 11th step, we will have all the docs with `beenTo` and `toGoTo` populated and sorted with saved date.

I hope this helps you out.

Note: while adding restaurants to `beenTo` and `toGoTo` array in user's doc, please only push `restaurant's _id` and not the complete `doc`.